# Passing undefined component as child using React

Tags: reactjs

I think code explains it better than words. So, this is what I am trying to do:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const IAmHiComponent = ({ children }) => <div>{children}</div>;

const COMPONENTS = {
  hi: IAmHiComponent
};

const Boom = ({ isLoaded, children }) => {
  if (!isLoaded) {
    return "Loading...";
  }

  return <div style={{ background: "red" }}>{children}</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const [loadedComponent, setLoadedComponent] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadedComponent("hi");
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  const MyLoadedComponent = COMPONENTS[loadedComponent];

  return (
    <Boom isLoaded={!!loadedComponent}>
      <MyLoadedComponent>Hi!!!</MyLoadedComponent>
    </Boom>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-benz-3nxy2?file=/src/App.js

it's simplified version, but basically what I am trying to do is to pass initially `undefined` component as a child and have kind of loading check in parent component and render `children` only when I know that everything is loaded.

And everything is working fine, but React is not happy about my approach and I am getting this error:

```
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

So I am trying to understand am I doing something terribly wrong? or just missing something small?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can simply conditionally include the child component:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [loadedComponent, setLoadedComponent] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadedComponent("hi");
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  const MyLoadedComponent = COMPONENTS[loadedComponent];

  return (
    <Boom isLoaded={!!loadedComponent}>
      { loadedComponent ? <MyLoadedComponent>Hi!!!</MyLoadedComponent> : null }
    </Boom>
  );
}
```

Comment: Well, as I said my example is simplified version of what I am trying to achieve. I know I can do that check, but then there is no point of passing ‘isLoading’ to ‘Boom’ component, because I would be doing same thing with that ‘loadedComponent’ conditional check.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `null` on `COMPONENTS` which gives `undefined` when `loadedComponent` is initially null.

You can add a check to only render the component when `loadedComponent` is not null like so :

```
export default function App() {
  const [loadedComponent, setLoadedComponent] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoadedComponent("hi");
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  const MyLoadedComponent = COMPONENTS[loadedComponent];

  return (
    <Boom isLoaded={!!loadedComponent}>
      {loadedComponent ? <MyLoadedComponent>Hi!!!</MyLoadedComponent> : null }
    </Boom>
  );
}
```

Comment: And that was my question from the very beginning, can I pass undefined as a child when I have that condition check inside parent. Because I know I can check it before passing it as a child, but then there is no point of passing that isLoaded to Boom component.

Comment: Then you already got the answer when React gave you that error. That you cannot. `undefined` is not a valid value and signifies the absence of a value. `null` on the other hand is a valid value. Although both are nullish, both have different meanings.

Comment: Well, not really. :) I still don’t understand why react is not happy about that undefined even when it’s not actually being used till it becomes defined. I mean, what’s the difference between checking that loadedComponent thing in Boom component instead of App component?

Comment: You can take a look at how JSX is actually translated using `React.createElement`.That should give you abetter understanding.

Comment: checked `createElement` and it makes sense now :) thanks for pointing to right direction.